# Repetition Keyword URL Subfolder + Slug?

Tags: url, keywords, clean-urls, categories, url-slug

here's the question. In this sense, it is not keyword stuffing in the URL if it is mentioned once as slug and category.

It would be more user friendly to have a short URL but it is questionable which could have a better impact on SEO even if it is minimal.

**Currently:**
example.com/eyes/burning-eyes

**More user-friendly:**
example.com/eyes/burning

Users would rather look for burning eyes than eyes burning.

**The search volume is** 
Burning eyes 2900
Eyes burning 2300

What would be your recommendation and why?

Thanks in forward :)

Answer (score 2):

Slug URLs are a minor ranking factor search engines use when determining a particular page or resource's relevance to a search query. So URLs will give low impact in the ranking. It's just used to identify web pages in a form that is easy to read for the end-user.

In my opinion, you should use slug like your page title, so if your page title *burning eyes* so your slug also should *burning-eyes*. But as I said before, it's only giving low impact, don't consider too deeply.